# Repeating operation in Android without alarm manager

Tags: java, android, kotlin, alarmmanager, android-workmanager

I created application for sending sms interval. I used AlarmManager, which worked good, however after few days of proper working (send SMS at established time). It starts sending at different time or desist.
As far as I know, this is often problem with AlarmManager.
Is there some trap with AM ? or maybe you know better solution, library for that type of problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

if the interval of time for sending the email is more than 15 minutes, I suggest you to use `JobScheduler`. That work really good over all android versions. I mentioned `more than 15 mins` because JobScheduler only can schedule at least every 15 mins on android 7 and over.

Answer (score 0):

`JobScheduler` is an option, but this is only available on Android API Level 21+ (Lollipop v5.0).
A better option is to use [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/?hl=ko), currently in beta, that provides the same functionality (and limits like the mentioned 15 minutes minimum interval) but down to API level 14.

You can find more information about WorkManager on [this series of blogs](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/introducing-workmanager-2083bcfc4712) and on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/?hl=ko).